# iPad not streaming videos to Vizio over Airplay

Tags: ipad, airplay

I am trying to watch study videos saved from the web on my Vizio TV. I download the video, convert to mp4 (using the Lifehacker encoding specs), import it into the TV app from my MBP then sync to my iPad. When I start the video on my iPad using the TV app and initialize Airplay I get an error message from the TV app: "This video is in a format that can't be streamed to this TV." I have tried purchased movies and those work fine over Airplay.
All videos in the TV app play without any problems. No problems with the wireless network.
I searched online for what the video specs should be and found [How to Make All Your Video Airplay-Compatible](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-make-all-your-video-airplay-compatible-5696764), but still get the same error message.
I have tried different encoders, different settings, etc. still getting the same error. What is the correct video specification to stream via Airplay? Or is this just not possible?

Video Encoding used from the Lifehacker link:

> Video Codec: H.264 (Main Profile)
> Video Bitrate: 5442kbps (anywhere between 5000 and 6000 kbps should be fine)
> Video Resolution 1280x720 (also known as 720p)
> Frames Per Second: 30 (or less)
> Audio Codec: AAC (Low Complexity)
> Audio Bitrate: 160kbps
> Audio Samplerate: 48 or 44.1 kHzVideo Codec: H.264 (Main Profile)
> Video Bitrate: 5442kbps (anywhere between 5000 and 6000 kbps should be fine)
> Video Resolution 1280x720 (also known as 720p)
> Frames Per Second: 30 (or less)
> Audio Codec: AAC (Low Complexity)
> Audio Bitrate: 160kbps
> Audio Samplerate: 48 or 44.1 kHz

iPad Air 2 (iOS 13.5.1)
MBP 13" 2020 (macOS 10.15.4)

Comment: What’s generating the error?  The iPad, the App, or the TV?   What format is it in?  What App are you using specifically? Can you play videos in the same format?  Which format video did work?  Which Mac?  What version of macOS?  There’s lots of missing info

Comment: @Allan I have added info to my original question for clarity.